# Will latest Linux Kernel drop syn packets with payload?

Tags: linux, tcp, syn

I am developing a software that client will send syn packet with payload to server, and server will check the syn packet's payload to do some extra work. It works fine on linux machine with kernel <=5.4. Now I am testing the client on Ubuntu 22.04(Kernel version is 5.15), and find that server can not receive the syn packet with payload from the client run on Unbuntu 22.04. I used tcpdump to watch the tcp traffic on client, and can see the syn packet with payload, but can not find it on server side. When I run the client on linux machine with kernel <= 5.4, it works fine.

Comment: The client run as VM in Oracle Virtual Box, maybe it's caused by Visual Box?

Comment: And I also tested client in docker container, and find the SYN packet will be sent to server, but the payload will be removed.

Comment: It seems that the issue is not caused by Linux kernel, but the virtual machine's network.